# Caption doesn't cover the last column

Tags: tables, captions

I have the following table:

```
\documentclass[12pt, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[font=bf,singlelinecheck=false, justification=raggedright]{caption}
\usepackage{ragged2e }
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{breakcites}
\usepackage{pdflscape}                                                              
\usepackage{booktabs,array,fixltx2e}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{1.8cm}}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}
\tiny
\captionsetup{size=scriptsize,format=hang}
\caption*{Table 6}
\vspace{-0.8 cm}
\begin{justify}
\textit{p}-values for Granger causality tests for survey questions and returns. This table presents the \textit{p}-value for Granger causality tests for sentiment indicators and sector return indices using individual survey questions. The results cover the period from January 1985 to December 2014. \textit{r}, \textit{g-cause}, and \textit{sent} denote return, Granger-cause, and sentiment, respectively.
\vspace{-0.3 cm}
\end{justify}
\label{tbl:Questionstables}
\begin{tabular}{lLLLLLLLL}
\hline
\addlinespace
 & \multicolumn{8}{l}{Questions} \\
\addlinespace
\hline
\addlinespace
Manufacturing & & & & & & & & \\
\addlinespace
 & Production trend observed in recent months & Assessment of order-book levels & Assessment of export order-book levels & Assessment of stocks of finished products & Production expectations for the months ahead & Selling price expectations for the months ahead & Employment expectations for the months ahead & Confidence Indicator (Q2 - Q4 + Q5) / 3 \\
sent g-cause return & 0.3300 & 0.0634 & 0.2654 & 0.7526 & 0.0584 & 0.4930 & 0.9956 & 0.0063 \\ 
 return g-cause sent & 0.0188 & 0.0385 & 0.1231 & 0.0114 & 0.0398 & 0.0026 & 0.0022 & 0.0399 \\ 
\addlinespace
Construction & & & & & & & & \\
\addlinespace
 & Building activity development over the past 3 months & Evolution of your current overall order books & Employment expectations over the next 3 months & Prices expectations over the next 3 months & Confidence Indicator (Q3 + Q4) / 2 & & & \\
sent g-cause return & 0.7873 & 0.0823 & 0.0014 & 0.1019 & 0.0705 \\ 
return g-cause sent & 0.2057 & 0.2423 & 0.1010 & 0.9985 & 0.1018 \\ 
\addlinespace
Retail Trade & & & & & & & & \\
\addlinespace
 & Business activity (sales) development over the past 3 months & Volume of stock currently hold & Orders expectations over the next 3 months & Business activity expectations over the next 3 months & Employment expectations over the next 3 months & Prices expectations over the next 3 months & Confidence Indicator (Q1 - Q2 + Q4) / 3 & \\
sent g-cause return & 0.5907 & 0.2856 & 0.0522 & 0.3200 & 0.2664 & 0.6740 & 0.1622 \\ 
return g-cause sent & 0.0210 & 0.5369 & 0.0626 & 0.0183 & 0.0396 & 0.1167 & 0.0146 \\ 
\addlinespace
Services & & & & & & & & \\
\addlinespace
 & Business situation development over the past 3 months & Evolution of the demand over the past 3 months & Expectation of the demand over the next 3 months & Evolution of the employment over the past 3 months & Expectations of the employment over the next 3 months & Expectations of the prices over the next 3 months & Confidence Indicator (Q1 + Q2 + Q3) / 3 & \\
sent g-cause return & 0.0831 & 0.0157 & 0.4882 & 0.1928 & 0.0857 & 0.1563 & 0.0892 \\ 
 return g-cause sent & 0.1218 & 0.1385 & 0.0356& 0.0009 & 0.0002 & 0.0067 & 0.0135 \\ 
sent g-cause return [Wald test] & 0.2336 & 0.0009 & 0.3356 & 0.3924 & 0.1648 & 0.1325 & 0.1137 \\ 
return g-cause sent[Wald test]  & 0.1733 & 0.0744 & 0.0299& 0.0006 & 0.0003& 0.0036  & 0.0346\\ 
\addlinespace
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}


\end{document}
```

For some reasons, the caption doesn't expand to the last column and I can't find away of adjusting it.

[image]

Comment: Your table goes beyond the text margins.  Add `\usepackage{showframe}` to your document and compile again.

Comment: `showframe` does not work correctly in `landscape`. But you can load `showframe` together with `scrhack` to show the page layout also for `landscape`.

Comment: @esdd how to load them together?

Comment: @esdd - Thanks for the hint, I wasn't aware of it!

Comment: @AhmedSalhin Load them both: `\usepackage{showframe}\usepackage{scrhack}`

Comment: @esdd I did that but it made no difference than loading \usepackage{showframe} only.

Comment: Then you have an old version of `scrhack` (part of the KOMA-Script bundle`. It needs at least version 3.19 which was released in september 2015. Current version is 3.21 But as @ArashEsbati told you, your table goes outside the textarea.

Comment: see the log: Overfull \hbox (68.38016pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 25--60
[] 

Overfull \hbox (628.0pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active
  TeX is warning you the content does not fit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TeX tells you exactly by how much the table is too large

```
 Overfull \hbox (68.38016pt too wide)
```

Changing your column to

```
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{1.5cm}}
```

makes it fit, although it still looks a bit cramped. Perhaps a re-wording of some of the cell headings would help, but that requires subject knowledge so I don't suggest any changes here.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using `geometry`, a `sidewaystable` environment and `tabularx`, you even can use `\scriptsize`: the `X` cells are approximately 21mm wide. I took the opportunity to add some improvements to the general layout:

```
\documentclass[12pt, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf,singlelinecheck=false, justification=raggedright]{caption}
\usepackage{ragged2e }
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{breakcites}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{booktabs,array, rotating}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\usepackage{tabularx, makecell}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}

\newgeometry{noheadfoot, bottom =3.3cm}\setcounter{table}{5}
\begin{sidewaystable*}
  \scriptsize \setcounter{table}{5} \captionsetup{font=scriptsize, format=hang, justification=justified, skip=6pt}
  \caption{\textit{p}-values for Granger causality tests for survey questions and returns. This table presents the \textit{p}-value for Granger causality tests for sentiment indicators and sector return indices using individual survey questions. The results cover the period from January 1985 to December 2014. \textit{r}, \textit{g-cause}, and \textit{sent} denote return, Granger-cause, and sentiment, respectively. }
  \label{tbl:Questionstables}
  \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textheight}{@{} > {\raggedright}l*{8}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}@{}}
    \toprule%
    & \multicolumn{8}{l}{Questions} \\%
    \midrule%
    \multicolumn{9}{@{\hspace{3em}}l}{\bfseries Manufacturing} \\[0.4ex]
                        & Production trend observed in recent months & Assessment of order-book levels & Assessment of export order-book levels & Assessment of stocks of finished products & Production expectations for the months ahead & Selling price expectations for the months ahead & Employment expectations for the months ahead & Confidence Indicator $\frac{\strut Q2 - Q4 + Q5}{3} $ \\
    sent g-cause return & 0.3300 & 0.0634 & 0.2654 & 0.7526 & 0.0584 & 0.4930 & 0.9956 & 0.0063 \\
    return g-cause sent & 0.0188 & 0.0385 & 0.1231 & 0.0114 & 0.0398 & 0.0026 & 0.0022 & 0.0399 \\
    \addlinespace
    \multicolumn{9}{@{\hspace{3em}}l}{\bfseries Construction} \\[0.4ex]
                        & Building activity development over the past 3 months & Evolution of your current overall order books & Employment expectations over the next 3 months & Prices expectations over the next 3 months & Confidence Indicator $ \frac{\strut Q3 + Q4}{2} $ & & & \\
    sent g-cause return & 0.7873 & 0.0823 & 0.0014 & 0.1019 & 0.0705 \\
    return g-cause sent & 0.2057 & 0.2423 & 0.1010 & 0.9985 & 0.1018 \\
    \addlinespace
    \multicolumn{9}{@{\hspace{3em}}l}{\bfseries Retail Trade} \\[0.4ex]
                        & Business activity (sales) development over the past 3 months & Volume of stock currently hold & Orders expectations over the next 3 months & Business activity expectations over the next 3 months & Employment expectations over the next 3 months & Prices expectations over the next 3 months & Confidence Indicator $\frac{\strut Q1 - Q2 + Q4}{3} $ & \\
    sent g-cause return & 0.5907 & 0.2856 & 0.0522 & 0.3200 & 0.2664 & 0.6740 & 0.1622 \\
    return g-cause sent & 0.0210 & 0.5369 & 0.0626 & 0.0183 & 0.0396 & 0.1167 & 0.0146 \\
    \addlinespace
    \multicolumn{9}{@{\hspace{3em}}l}{\bfseries Services} \\[0.4ex]
                        & Business situation development over the past 3 months & Evolution of the demand over the past 3 months & Expectation of the demand over the next 3 months & Evolution of the employment over the past 3 months & Expectations of the employment over the next 3 months & Expectations of the prices over the next 3 months & Confidence Indicator $\frac{\strut Q1 + Q2 + Q3}{3} $ & \\
    sent g-cause return & 0.0831 & 0.0157 & 0.4882 & 0.1928 & 0.0857 & 0.1563 & 0.0892 \\
    return g-cause sent & 0.1218 & 0.1385 & 0.0356& 0.0009 & 0.0002 & 0.0067 & 0.0135 \\
    \addlinespace[0.5ex]
    \makecell[t]{sent g-cause return\\{}[Wald test]} & 0.2336 & 0.0009 & 0.3356 & 0.3924 & 0.1648 & 0.1325 & 0.1137 \\
    \makecell[t]{return g-cause sent\\{} [Wald test]} & 0.1733 & 0.0744 & 0.0299& 0.0006 & 0.0003& 0.0036 & 0.0346\\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
\end{sidewaystable*}

\end{document}
```

[image]